# How to embed react component on other domains?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, embedding

I have created a simple React component. I want that component to use as a plugin or widget. I have taken help from [Writing embeddable Javascript plugin with React & Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239731/writing-embeddable-javascript-plugin-with-react-webpack) and manage to set my webpack as below:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: './app/components/FirstWidgetIndex.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    library: 'tracking',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  }
```

And my component is as below:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class FirstWidget extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="setting-fullpage">
                <p>React Widget</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    //
}

module.exports = FirstWidget
```

And my `FirstWidgetIndex` file (entry point of webpack) is as follows:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './FirstWidget.js';

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Now, I want to add this `FirstWidget` as an embeddable widget. I am calling it on third party domain in an `html` file as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/jsx" src="https://mydomain/firstWidget"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Testing React Widget</p>
        <div id='app'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But its not rendering my widget on the `html` page. Can anyone please suggest if I am missing anything?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue you are facing, but important to do none-the-less - use webpack in [production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/) mode and [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html) as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell where react will render, for example:

**FirstWidget.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class FirstWidget extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.js**

This is your entry point in webpack

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './FirstWidget.js';

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

In your *index.html* you need to have a tag with `app` id.

```
<div id='app'></div>
```

> Note: The code in `index.js` needs to be like it's above and it should be the entry point in your webpack configuration.

Comment: I think you mean `App ` by `FirstWidget`.

Comment: When I am accessing that component in my react application it is rendering but when in third party its not. can you please confirm if I am adding correct js file in index.html?

Comment: You miss the last part of my answer: **In your index.html you need to have a tag with app id**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166463/discussion-between-arnold-gandarillas-and-triyugi-narayan-mani).