# How to export ReactJS app as package to be used in other app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am using **webpack** and **babel** for building my app and app is building successfully in file bundle.js.

I have index.jsx file that has this code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

App component has bunch of other components loading up.

I have index.html file in the same app.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**I am opening index.html file from system directory, directly in browser and app is running fine.**

What I want to do is to use bundle.js file and load my script in another html/javascript application, that run same application inside it.

I have found this [Writing embeddable Javascript plugin with React & Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239731/writing-embeddable-javascript-plugin-with-react-webpack) link that shows how he managed to use it.

Where he uses

```
export const init = (config) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyReactApp config={config} />, someSelector);
}
```

How can I convert my index.jsx file so that can be used in another app, same way it is being used in answer of link given.

Comment: Use a UMD library: http://bob.yexley.net/umd-javascript-that-runs-anywhere/ and https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

Comment: I have added it in webpack.config.js file as  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: 'MyApp',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },

Answer (score 1):

Like he says in the other answer

```
<script src="./bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  MyApp.yourExportedFunction();
</script>
```

But that's just for using an exported function.  It looks like you want to have your entire app render in a different index.html file in some other app, so in your index.html of the other app you would need:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

and

```
<script src=".path/to/other/project/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then the app will render inside your `div#app` tag because that's what your library does:

```
render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Its working, but I shared link because I wanted to modify my index.jsx or html file to receive some parameters, send from where I want to use. just like in link

Comment: Then you would have to export the function that does the rendering like he did and pass your parameters to the function as shown in his example.