# is it possible to run two different versions of ReactJS on the same page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello everyone I am wondering if is possible to run two version of ReactJS on the same page , something similar to `jQuery.noConflict()`.

With a bit of research i have found two interesting things :

> **Two Reacts Won’t Be Friends**
>
> While I’m happy that everybody seems to be converging on NPM in 2015 and NPM wants developers to use it for managing front-end dependencies, it still has rough edges. The biggest problem with using NPM for front-end dependencies is that if two packages specify a library like React as a dependency, they might get two separate copies of React. Even worse, they might get different versions of it. This works fine for something like Node, but not for browser libraries that want to mess with the same global mutable DOM! NPM tried to solve this with peerDependencies but all hell broke loose and they’re backing out.

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375#.hfx35f6hl

And an issue on github: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1939

However is not clear for me how we could wrap & delivery our ReactJS widgets in order they could run without conflicts on a page using other version of ReactJS .

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However is not clear for me how we could wrap & delivery our ReactJS widgets in order they could run without conflicts on a page using other version of ReactJS.

You can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) with [reactify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactify) to load your JS and version of ReactJS without conflicting with another ReactJS version that may be loaded on the page.

More information is available here:

- [Embeddable JavaScript widget with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454029/embeddable-javascript-widget-with-react)