# React libraries (different versions) loading onto Webpage

Tags: reactjs, webpack, conflict

Background: 
I have multiple webpages created using different library versions of angular, react, Vue etc.

Now we are creating some widgets to plugin to those pages. I want to use latest version of react. Webpack is my bundler, I know it bundles up my libraries together with the source code.

Question:
There may be few pages with libraries like react loaded on to the pages at global namespace. I have done couple of rounds of testing for my widget, and haven't found any issues. Is there any possibility of getting conflicts with different versions of react libs loaded on to the parent page. Is there any way to handle it smartly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783430/is-it-possible-to-run-two-different-versions-of-reactjs-on-the-same-page could be your answer.

Comment: MattYao, This is a good pointer. I am expecting more clear steps. Solution given is very generic wepack and browserify. I am already using webpack, do I need to have any specific configuration?