# Micro-frontends: Web application with multiple frontend frameworks

Tags: php, reactjs, vue.js, backbone.js, software-design

This is actually a software architecture problem. I have a huge monolithic web application which is built using PHP and backbone js. Now I would like to introduce a new front-end framework like react/vue. I wonder what is a better approach to solve this issue. I am thinking of an approach to build micro applications, for example, an application that is responsible for rendering left panel only. In that case, what would the communication between server and client? How will the main application be able to render this micro application?

If you can suggest any better approach please feel free to share.

Comment: Do some research, make some attempts and if you run into some _specific_ issue, come back, show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. In it's current form, this question is _way_ too broad and unspecific for SO. It will most likely also only give you opinionated answers, which are off-topic here. SO is a FAQ for questions that have a clear answer, it's not a forum for discussions, which this question will produce.

Comment: You should find my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57128892/6497675) insightful.

Answer (score 0):

All I was looking for is this `Micro frontends`

https://medium.com/@tomsoderlund/micro-frontends-a-microservice-approach-to-front-end-web-development-f325ebdadc16

> Hope this helps. Sometimes I don't really like the approach of those
>   intellects who can neither help nor take a question positively. Even
>   though the question is broad but I believe the answer can help a lot
>   of people out there.