# Micro Front End / Web Components / Vue Router Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, web-component, micro-frontend

I have stucked with a issue, Below is the scenario :

I have developed a **vue application (my-admin micro app)**  which has 4 - 5 screens/components (manage user , manage notifications ,manage roles etc) and i created a **router.js** where i have wrote following :

```
...imports... 
Vue.use(VueRouter);
// }
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'main-layout',
    component: MainLayout,
    children:[
      {
        path : 'manage-user',
        name : 'manage-user',
        component : ManageUserComponent
      },
      {
        path : 'manage-role',
        name : 'manage-role',
        component : ManageRoleComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

and i imported this router object in my **main.js** like below :

```
...imports...
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

and at last i **wrap my this micro app as web component (MainLayout component) in main.js** as below :

```
const myAdmin = wrap(Vue,MainLayout)

window.customElements.define('my-admin', myAdmin)
```

i **build** this micro app with following command :

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-admin ./src/main.js",
```

thats all for this micro app . ***and it is running perfectly if i run this micro app individually.***

But in my scenario , i have a **shell application (my-shell) which is developed in Vue** only. and this shell application also has its **own vue router and imported in its main.js** like below :

. shell router :

```
...imports... 

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'container',
    component: Container,
    children:[
      {
        path : 'admin',
        name : 'admin-microapp',
        component : AdminMicroAppContainerComponent
      },
      {
        path : 'other',
        name : 'other-microapp',
        component : OtherMicroAppContainerComponent
      }
    ]
 }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

and i **imported this router object in to my-shell's main.js** like below :

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and **inside my-shell's index.html i added  tags** (inside )to load my micro apps buid (my-admin.js file) like below :

```
 <script src="../assets/my-admin/dist/my-admin.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/other-microapps/dist/micro-app.js"></script>
```

**But when i am starting my-shell application . it is throwing below error** :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router.
```

What can I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Could you fix this issue? Or did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 4):

I've not tried recreatting this scenario, however I can spot the obvious reason why it doesn't work.

Lets briefly look at what happens when you launch an SPA.
[image]

Router's are initialize at the beginning, i.e `new Vue()` and your sub-apps are attached midway i.e on the Dom Rerender, following this sequence, you can't jump from mid-app back to the top without breaking things either the initial router is discarded or the new one is rejected.

My advice:

> ### Don't use vue-router in your subapps (web components), use a lightweight code to handle routing.

In my experience doing micro-frontend architecture, the whole goal is to stick to the SOLID pattern as much as possible. If your sub-apps are complex to the extent that they require vue-router for routing, then you're not doing it right*.

Typically, a sub-app should be such that does only one thing.

e.g In a business SaaS software for example, A customer micro app is only responsible for

1. Creating new customer (pop up modal)
2. Listing Customers
3. Viewing a single customer's transaction report
4. Editing customer informattion (pop up modal)

Handling customer payments, debts and complex charting reports is each handled by another sub-app.

Only 2 and 3 require routing and we handled that with `v-if` statements.

Comment: you are correct but my entire application is very large scale application where each micro app would be complex application instead of simple single usecase web component.

Comment: Then I think you're implementing it wrong. If each sub-application is so complex you need a routing system, you shouldn't deploy each sub-application as a web-component

Comment: A better approach for you might be to use piral.io or https://single-spa.js.org/.
They're a bit more complex to setup, but the'll give you that level of flexibility you seek.