# How to include an Angular 7 application in an existing html file and website?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7

I have on one side an existing website, on the other I have an Angular 7 application component.

I'd like to edit my existing `someusecase.html` and reuse my Angular 7 application like so e.g.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>How to import Angular 7 App?</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

What would I need to include in the html for this to work? I'm after e.g. something equivalent to:

```
<script src="/ui/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/components/Application.js"></script>
```

In other words, is it possible to reuse and activate an Angular 7 Application within a `<div>` scope inside an existing webpage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to embed an angular app into another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604189/how-to-embed-an-angular-app-into-another-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Run

```
ng build
```

2) got into the `dist` folder

3) Copy & paste all of the files there, to your original app, **except** for the `index.html` file.

4) Open the not-copied `index.html` file

5) Copy all of the `<script>` tags in this file, into your `someusecase.html` file, **at the same spot**.

6) use your app component selector wherever you want your angular application to be displayed.

Note that this is only informational : in real life, this should be automated, because you would have to do this manipulation **on every build**.

Comment: Also make sure sequence of js files imports

Comment: @NitinDaddikar that was implicit but yes, indeed !

Comment: And be warned this may change in Angular 8... (dual build will change the number of scripts to be copied)