# Muliple SPA's on different repositories using Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, micro-frontend

Was supposed to use Angular 7 + single-spa combo (https://single-spa.js.org/) for the approach mentioned above. Basically, I want to be able to:

1. Separate Repositories for each micro application
2. Each application would be managed by a different team
3. Each application can / or cannot be a stand alone
4. A root application that brings all the applications together

We were able to achieve this using Angular 7, but the direction suddenly became to use Angular 8. Single-spa-angular does not yet support Angular 8, and Im afraid we can't wait that long before it gets supported, issue being tracked here: https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa-angular/issues/83

Angular 8 isn't capable of importing applications that are already built. Or atleast I'm a noob when it comes to it and I'm not aware.

Answer (score 0):

In order to consider all advantages you want, you may want another techniques for micro-frontend.

e.g What about using [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) (aka Web Components)?

Here is a full explanation of each techniques.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719127/6432698