# How to embed angular app on another website?

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, frontend, embed

I have application written in Angular 7 and i would like to embed it on another website (website is not specified). The idea is that two websites are completly idependent (different servers etc.) and i would like to present view from angular application. Something like iframe but iframe is not suitable for me since i will need comunication between those websites and styling iframe to be aware of it's content is nightmare. In the end user shouldn't be able to tell that there are two different websites there. When you operate on the view from angular app it uses it's backend and when you operate on external site it uses it's own BE and so on.

I have been searching for an answer but i haven't found anything. Angular Elements doesn't do the trick since (if i understood it right) it "exports" components that are usable outside the framework and i want to display existing view.

I found article here [how to embed an angular app into another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604189/how-to-embed-an-angular-app-into-another-app) but it was some time ago and none of the solutions seems to fit me. I'm wondering wether there any new approaches to this topic?

The best would be generic solution like iframe where i just put tag into another website but approaches per technology is also welcome.

Thanks for help!