# How to use an entire Angular app in a website?

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to use my Angular 7 app (not that small - `main.js` ~5MB and `vendor.js` ~10MB) in another website (not even knowing anything technical about it yet). Let's say that it is just a part of a bigger process that should be embedded in order to give extra functionality. What options (if any) are there?

Comment: just host your app somewhere then in your new site add the link of old site or preview of old site [ just like people use entire google map in their web page]

Comment: @Frost The app is already hosted in Azure as a website. How to preview the Angular app (old site) in the new site (have not used google maps so far)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite an interesting topic, embedding Angular apps in different projects. Personally, I haven't had to deal with that yet but fortunately there's a well-written SO post.

See [Various ways to embed Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719127/12221382)

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I was just checking this right now... It seems there are many options. I have to try them though.