# how to embed one angular project into another project on click button

Tags: angular

I have created two independent angular9 apps and different repository and try access to one another after click a button need to load another app on top of that app

Comment: is both applications in 2 different URL? are you searching for `iframe`?

Comment: looks similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604189/how-to-embed-an-angular-app-into-another-app